# Accessing parameters in a SQL stored Procedure in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a stored procedure that uses an integer parameter and dateadd() to create a timestamp that's used to filter results in a where clause. I am getting "Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 3 at position 2 : SQL compilation error: error line 9 at position 53 invalid identifier 'X_DAYS_BACK'" when I try to run the procedure below. If I move the return line above the create table line the procedure successfully runs and the return string includes the actual value of x_days_back (e.g. base.ITEM updated for last 3 days.).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BASE.ITEM_LOAD_test(X_DAYS_BACK INTEGER)
returns string not null
language SQL
as
$$
BEGIN
  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE BASE.TEMP_DELTA_ITEM (
        ID STRING
      )
   AS
    SELECT
        SOURCE||KEY AS ID
      FROM BASE.SUPPLIER_CATALOG_ITEM
      WHERE
        CDP__ETL_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP >= DATEADD(Day ,-1*X_DAYS_BACK, CURRENT_DATE);
    
    drop TABLE BASE.TEMP_DELTA_ITEM;
    
    RETURN 'base.ITEM updated for last ' ||  X_DAYS_BACK || ' days.' ;
END;
$$
```

How do I access a parameter of a SQL stored procedure within a function such as dateadd? I know it's a preview feature, so is this not currently implemented or?

Answer (score 0):

Toss a colon in front of the variable/parameter:

```
DATEADD(day, -1*:X_DAYS_BACK, CURRENT_DATE);
```

Their documentation isn't amazing for SQL stored procedures but there is mention of this [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding) where it states:

> You can use a variable in a SQL statement. (This is sometimes referred to as binding a variable.) Prefix the variable name with a colon.

Comment: Thanks for the help, exactly what I was looking for! SQL stored procedures are still in preview and I think the paucity of the documentation reflects that.

Comment: The documentation is definitely lacking. Even the verbiage they use here "This is sometimes referred to as binding a variable" is REALLY BAD. This is concatenation of a variable and, if I'm not mistaken, could lead to a sql injection attack where proper binding would prevent that.